# Is there a way to extract conditionally a value from a JSON object with a JSONPath based on another value inside the same object?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonpath

I have the following JSON object

```
{"id":"15", "value":1}
```

I want to extract the value 1 if and only if id == 15.

The most relevant expression I tried was

```
$?(@.id=="15").value
```

but it doesn't seem to work, I only obtain no match.

I use json.net in C#.

Comment: The [JSONPath proposal](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) is somewhat ambiguous about whether conditional queries should work on the root object, however Json.NET's support for JSONPath queries is only specified to work for objects **inside arrays** not objects inside objects or root objects. ...

Comment: ... For confirmation see this comment by JamesNK: [JSONPath scripts not executing correctly for objects #1256](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1256#issuecomment-289134144): *I'm not sure about this. Nothing in the JSONPath says that filters should apply to objects.*  Sometimes workarounds can be found, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45298348/3744182) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39453636/3744182).

Comment: See also [How to make SelectTokens() select root element if jsonpath expression evaluates to true](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68983688) and [JsonPath: Selecting root level field if satisfies a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25031187) which make it clear that the standard doesn't clearly define whether it should be possible to filter the root object itself.  I think a query like yours could be made to work if your object were inside an array, i.e. `[{"id":"15", "value":1}]`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to learn what is jsonPath for.It is impossible to use jsonPath to extract something from one only property.  this is much easier

```
var jObj=JObject.Parse(json);

int? value = jObj["id"].ToString() == "15" ? (int)jObj["value"] : null; //1
```

json path is working only with collections, so move your object inside of the array

```
    var json = "[{\"id\":\"15\", \"value\":1}]";
    
    var jArr = JArray.Parse(json);
    
    int id= (int) jArr.SelectToken("$[?(@.id=='15')].value"); //1
    //or
    int id = (int) jArr.SelectToken("$[?(@.id=='15')]")["value"]; //1
```

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your answer, but I'm "stuck" in the sense that I can only manipulate the json through a jsonPath and no other way. I understand after reading @dbc comments now that what I want to do is just impossible with jsonPath.